# Non-separable differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'-xy^2=2xy+x^2$

I can't find a way to separate this differential equation. How would I put it in 'quadrature form'?

Comment: You'd need an integrating factor to handle it.

Comment: We haven't learnt that yet, only separable differential equations. So I just need to put this equation in terms of integral, which I don't understand..

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do that; Riccati equations are usually not easy to solve. Are you sure you wrote the problem correctly? Anything removing the square from the $y$ would make the problem far easier. Though hm: $y'=xy^2+2xy+x^2=xy^2+2xy+x-x+x^2=x(1+y)^2-x+x^2$. So with $z=1+y$ you have $z'=xz^2+x+x^2$, which is not as bad, albeit still pretty bad.

Comment: Yep, just checked the equation is written correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Riccati equation,which are not in general easy to solve.

If you can find a particular solution $y_1$, then, the substitution $z=\frac{1}{y-y_1}$ will reduce it to a linear equation in $z$,which can be handled easily.

Another approach is to set $y=-\frac{z'}{zx}$ which leads to

$xz''-(1+2x^2)z'+x^4z=0$, which is linear homogeneous and may be solved by series methods. If you want to expand around $x_0=0$ you will use the method of Frobenius.